toga.ImageView not showing image under 'if' condition
I am trying to create an app with a dropdown menu, on click then it will show an image - code attached:
        selection = toga.Selection(
            items=[
                {"name": "Select a muscle group"},
                {"name": "Traps"},
                {"name": "Delts"},
                {"name": "Triceps"},
                {"name": "Biceps"},
                {"name": "Forearms"},
                {"name": "Chest"},
                {"name": "Abs"},
                {"name": "Lats"},
                {"name": "Legs"},

            ],
            accessor="name",
            on_change=self.clicked,

        )

        # Select Bob explicitly
        selection.value = selection.items[0]

        # selection.value = selection.items.find("Traps")

        # Which item is currently selected? This will print "Charlie"
        print(f"Currently selected: {selection.value}")

        button = toga.Button(
            "Say Hello!",
            on_press=self.say_hello,
            style=Pack(padding=5)
        )

        image_from_path = toga.Image("anat_one.png")

        main_box.add(name_box)
        main_box.add(selection)
        main_box.add(button)
        # self.triceps(main_box, image_from_path)
        # print('no.1' + str(image_from_path))

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    def clicked(self, selection):
        print("Clicked row", selection.value, "of table")
        box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        image_from_path = toga.Image("anat_one.png")

        if 'Triceps' in str(selection.value):
        # if 'Triceps' in str(selection.value):
            box.add(toga.ImageView(image_from_path))
            print('Triceps are proper ' + str(image_from_path))
            print('box is: ' + str(box))


    async def say_hello(self, widget):
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            response = await client.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42")

    payload = response.json()

    self.main_window.info_dialog(
        greeting(self.name_input.value),
        payload["body"],
        )

def main():
    return HelloWorld()

specifically, I added 'on_change = self.clicked' to the 'selection' dropdown menu which calls the function 'clicked' (also can be found in the code above):
    def clicked(self, selection):
        print("Clicked row", selection.value, "of table")
        box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))
        image_from_path = toga.Image("anat_one.png")

        if 'Triceps' in str(selection.value):
        # if 'Triceps' in str(selection.value):
            box.add(toga.ImageView(image_from_path))
            print('Triceps are proper ' + str(image_from_path))
            print('box is: ' + str(box))

However, although the image exists and it shows that box.add exists, nothing appears when "Triceps" are selected from the dropdown menu
screenshot of selected dropdown option

You added your image to a Box, but you never added that Box to anything, so it's not going to be displayed.

@jasonharper many thanks, I was being silly - seems to have solved the issue
